# scroll and position: fixed inside overflow: scroll div

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

I have a `position: fixed` div besides a div with long text inside a div with `overflow: scroll`. I want the text to scroll even if my cursor is hovering over the fixed div (which is the normal behavior when the window would be the scrolling element).

I made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jM2Eh/1/

I basically want the text to scroll while scrolling hovering over the red box.

UPDATE: I am using Twitter bootstrap in this particular case and updated the fiddle accordingly.

If JavaScript is needed for that, that would also be ok.

UPDATE2: I also tried this solution, but that causes weird flickering effects:

http://jsfiddle.net/jM2Eh/16/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j5BLm/13/ - seems to work only when div is set to 100%  height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using padding-left on your text node instead of using two columns?

http://jsfiddle.net/j5BLm/15/

```
.text {
    padding-left: 50%;
}
```

Another possible solution is to use pointer-events: none if you don't care about IE:

http://jsfiddle.net/codedigger/jM2Eh/18

Comment: You also set the height to 100%. Unfortunately this is not an option.

Comment: Another possible solution is to use pointer-events: none if you don't care about IE: http://jsfiddle.net/codedigger/jM2Eh/18/

Comment: I'd set this to the accepted answer if you updated your post with your second comment (which works fine for me). But I also have to point out that my JS solution also works now: http://jsfiddle.net/chmanie/jM2Eh/19/

Comment: Done, hope it helped.